# IMap Hazelcast size operation

Tags: hazelcast

If you have several nodes in Hazelcast will the return value in IMap.size() method return the size of the map in that node or the total size of all objects associated with that map distributed through all nodes?

Looking through the javadocs, it doesn't show that method being overridden, so I imagine that method call won't return what would normally be expected in a non-distributed map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns the estimated size of the complete distributed map. Estimated because it just gets the count of elements in a partition at a given point in time, since multiple partition are operated one after another that does not need to be the 100% real amount but it is if you get the size but not mutating the actual map.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. If I make the call IMap iMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap(mapName) the map I'm returned doesn't necessarily have all the elements in it, just the ones that happened to be stored locally correct? Only when I request for an object that is not stored locally in the map will it then make the call for it?

Comment: That is correct but IMap::size is a distributed operation and requests the local sizes of all nodes and accumulates them. Since the operation is distributed and might take "some" time but the cluster doesn't stop to respond mean while it is considered just an estimation.